# PHPMAILER trying to make image input multiple

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm trying to make an input where the user can select multiple images in an mail.

I'm getting an error that I need help with:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
```

HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="file" class="file" name="image[]" id="image[]" multiple/>
   </form>
```

```
for($ct=0;$ct<count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);$ct++)
{
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['image']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename =$_FILES['image']['name'][$ct];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qualify your array value with `is_array()` ([Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)) before running the `for` loop:

```
if(is_array($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
    for($ct=0;$ct<count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);$ct++){
       ...
       ...
    }
}
```

I will assume you're also already checking the error codes for each uploaded and that you have an `else` for what if anything you need to do if the given data is not an array.

Also be aware that your `id` tag is invalid for HTML4. It would seem to be awkward to have to reference an id tag with square brackets in the name, I suggest removing the brackets from the `id`.

> ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).